# Create stored procedure to a drop table or refer to table with the parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My question is about how to refer to an object in a stored procedure. I want to know if something like this is possible:

```
create proc drop_table @tablename ??
as
drop table @tablename
```

What about something like this?

```
create or alter proc select_col @col_name nvarchar(50), @table_nbame nvarchar(50)
as
select @col_name
from @table_nbame
```

Can I create a variable and refer to a table in a SP?

Comment: @DeanOC my question is more about how to refer to an object in a stored procedure...

Comment: @David if you look at the link, thats exactly what it explains... how to do what you want to do, which requires dynamic SQL.

Comment: Wanting these types of generic procedures is really considered an anti-pattern in T-SQL though. Not only does it open you up to SQL Injection, but dynamic SQL is harder to test and maintain. Its not what T-SQL was designed for.

Comment: @DaleK, ok so it is not possible to refer to objects e.g. tables in a stored procedure. And I have to go get the information from sys.tables... Right?

Comment: @DaleK The answer and question in the link...

Comment: The answer is using `sys.tables` to test whether a given table exists... your question doesn't mention that, but if thats what you need then thats how you do it.

Comment: @DaleK. my question is about how to refer to an object e.g. a table in a SP. And if that is possible. But I understand that it is not possible without dynamic sql. Thanks.

Comment: Dropping and creating database objects should be a design time operation, not a run time operation. The need to drop or create a table at run time is a strong indication of a faulty database design.

Comment: BTW, SQL Server has a data type alias that is used for object names - it's called `sysname` and it's an alias for `nvarchar(128)` - so `nvarchar(50)` might not be long enough.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: What I was looking for was quotename. I don't want to drop tabels I wanted to know how to refer to objects in a SP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot drop the table when passing parameters without getting errors. But if you can redirect errors into checking again if the table exists or not, you can get the desired outcome:

```
create procedure drop_table_smartly
    @tablename varchar(20)
as
begin    
    declare @cmd varchar(50) = (select 'drop table '+ @tablename)
    exec (@cmd)
end
```

So now by using below execution, you can drop any table

```
exec drop_table_smartly 'droper'
```

Please be informed, that whatever others have warned you about these are right. you should only use in production after proper testing (don't use in production)

Comment: `declare @cmd as varchar(50) =  'drop table ' + QuoteName( @tablename );` will suffice, no need to `select`. Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.